# I have added JQuery reference to masterpage but it wont work

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I added 
`<script src="/Scripts/1.7.2.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
to my master page, then removed the reference from my Jquery webpart. Now it won't work? I also used the designer tool to get the path. why won't it work.
This is for SharePoint 2013

Comment: Check on log (or with fiddler) if jquery is loaded, maybe you have included a wrong path ? In this example it search http://myhost/scripts/1.7.2.jquery.min.js (maybe jquery-1.7.2.min.js ?).

Comment: Fiddler shows the path being loaded but no content type and a body of 0. I used the built in URL tool to find the path inside SharepPoint designed, so one would assume its in the correct place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the full path to the file or

```
<script src="Scripts/1.7.2.jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i have it set to <script src="../../Scripts/1.7.2.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
but still no go.

Comment: Now the script wont work on any of the subsites. what do I need to do in order to get those to work?

Comment: Use the full path. `code`<script src="www.site.com/Scripts/1.7.2.jquery.min.js"></script>`code`